# How to store only one value per attribute in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to store only one value per attribute in Xcode
If a new value is stored then I want to overwrite the first on, to keep only one value
one attribute = one value

Is there an option for that ?
Or should I delete existing value before storing the new value ?

(I learn core data, I may not use it right...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data really only consists of single key-value pairs I would make use of UserDefaults and not core data. Specially if the data is rather simple and not "interacting on each other". The documentation can be found here [UserDefaults doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), for examples see [UserDefaults in Swift 4](https://medium.com/@nimjea/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79)

Comment: Thank you that’s exactly what i wanted !